# JSON not loading into dropdown list from ajax call using jQuery loadJSON plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, html-select

I'm a noob using Ajax and I could really use some help.  I've been going through the tutorial for the [loadJSON plugin here](http://jquery-load-json.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/categories-ajax.html).   Has anyone used this plugin with ajax?

I must be missing a crucial step because I can't get the `'regions.js'` file to load into the dropdown menu.  I have copied and pasted the code, created the region.js and towns.js files, and also looked at the "network' panel in Chrome Dev Tools to see if the script is returning anything.  The script is being called and the `Header response is 200`, its using GET method and I can see the `JSON` loaded in the Preview tab.  However, when i check in the console for the `$('.region');` value/s, it returns an empty array.

Would someone show me how to get this tutorial to work correctly?  I suppose the author thinks readers already understand how to do this since he didn't include the ajax code.  Thanks.

HTML:

```
<label for="Region">Region</label>
<select name="Region" >
    <option value="" class="regions"></option>
</select>

<label for="Town">Town</label>
<select name="Town" id="Town" multiple="multiple" >
    <option class="towns" >-</option>
</select>
```

regions.js (JSON)

```
{
    "regions":[
        {
            "value": 1,
            "text": "East Europe"
        },
        {
            "value": 2,
            "text": "West Europe"
        },
        {
            "value": 3,
            "text": "Middle Europe"
        }
    ]
}
```

towns.js (JSON)

```
{
    "towns":[
        {
            "value": 17,
            "text": "Belgrade"
        },
        {
            "value": 18,
            "text": "Buchurest"
        },
        {
            "value": 19,
            "text": "Moscov"
        },
        {
            "value": 20,
            "text": "Kiev"
        }
    ]
}
```

jQuery

```
$('#Region').loadJSON('regions.js');
```

jQuery

```
$('#Region').change(function() {
            var id = $(this).val();
            $('#Town').loadJSON('towns' + id + '.js');
    });
```

Comment: You missed the id attribute for the region select box. <select name="Region" id="Region"> .

Comment: The towns shouldn't be in `towns.js`. They should be in `towns1.js`, `towns2.js`, and so on. The numbers in the filenames match the values in `regions.js`.

Comment: +1 to both Ananth and Barmar. Each listed answer to single issue.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> If the town array is placed in the towns1.js, towns2.js, towns3.js files, the following code will load the towns dropdown list:

Your town data file is not named correctly.

The web page has a bug,

```
<select name="Region" >
```

should be:

```
<select name="Region" id="Region" >
```

The ID is necessary for `$("#Region")` to work.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the js file you are trying to load could not be found by the compiler
you should give the right path for getting that file
may be

$('#Region').loadJSON('./regions.js');

if the file is in separate folder specify the folder name too

$('#Region').loadJSON('./js/regions.js');

where js is name of the folder..

Comment: Thanks, Sharau.  However, all files are in the same folder (.html, .css, .js, imgs)